# Should I rely on Platform.OS or rely on Platform Specific Code in React Native?

Tags: react-native, optimization

I am co-developing an application and in some places, the application relies a lot on Platform.OS checks. However, my gut feeling is that it's the bad approach to the problem, because same checks will eventually have to be made a lot of times. Sure, equality checks are fast, but it'd probably make more sense to make the Metro bundler take care of the problem by using Problem Specific Code (as explained [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions)) then re-run the same code many times in the runtime? Or am I missing something or trying to over-optimize things?

The Platform.OS check is primarily done in the application's design system components.

Comment: Someone will give more detailed answer, but in a word, you should use platform specific extensions if your component / logic drastically changes between platforms, and use Platform.OS / Platform.select if only a small part of the code changes. There's no need to have multiple copies of the same file just because of a single line.